# JavaScript get underneath element by the upper element

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to get underneath element by the element over it.

I am implementing a drag and drop the use case is the drag handle can move freely over the page but only can drop if it's over a div, section and etc element. It cannot be dropped over anchors or buttons or input elements.

I have the drag handle reference with me but I am not able to get the element underneath it.

Is it possible in plain javascript?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you can get childs of any element by using js

Comment: Thanks, guys did by using elementsFromPoint.